# "ionic3" fails if there are no internet connection

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic3

I'm new with developing ionic apps and I had some trouble when disconnected from the internet on my PC.

Description:

If I have an internet connection (wi-fi) I can run "ionic serve" without problems, but when I disconnect the wi-fi and try to run "ionic serve" I get this error message:

```
"events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Kayl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Kayl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Kayl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)"
```

Steps to Reproduce:
Disconnect from wireless
try run "ionic serve"